# How to add a JSON array to every JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have the following `JSON` Object:

```
{
  "status": "CREATED",
  "overrides": {
    "name": "test_override"
  },
  "package_name": "test",
  "name": "app1",
  "defaults": {
    "job": {
      "example": {
        "executors_num": "2",
        "freq_in_mins": "180",
        "executors_mem": "256M",
        "job_name": "batch_example"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert the above `JSON` object to something like this. Basically add an array to every nested object

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "status": "CREATED"
    },
    {
      "obj": "overrides",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "test_override"
        }
        ]
        },
        {
          "package_name": "test"
        },
        {
          "name": "app1"
        },
        {
          "obj": "defaults",
          "children": [
          {
           "obj": "job",
           "children": [
           {
            "obj": "example",
            "children": [
            {
              "executors_num": "2",
              "freq_in_mins": "180",
              "executors_mem": "256M",
              "job_name": "batch_example"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's what I have in terms of code:

```
function traverse(o, d) {
  for (i in o) {
    if (typeof(o[i])=="object") {
      console.log(i, o[i]);
      // considering only 'default' obj for now
      if(i === 'defaults') {
        d.children.push( {obj: i, "children" :[ o[i] ]});
      }
      traverse(o[i], d);
    }
  }
  return d;
}
```

I end up with this instead:

```
{"children":[{"obj":"defaults",
"children":[{"job":{"example":
{"executors_num":"2","freq_in_mins":"180","executors_mem":"256M","job_name":"batch_example"}}}]}]}
```

But i seem to be struck, not sure how to add the `children` array to every nested object. Any pointers?

Comment: What's the exact problem? Any error messages?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out how to add the array to every nested object.. I end up with this :

     `{"children":[{"obj":"defaults"},{"children":[{"job":{"example":{"executors_num":"2","freq_in_mins":"180","executors_mem":"256M","job_name":"batch_example"}}}]}]}`

Comment: Please update your example with the code from your comment.

Comment: @whipdancer updated the example with the code..

Comment: Can you ad any Fiddle/Pnlkr?

Comment: How do you call `traverse`?

Comment: @TaoP.R.
 `var destJson = {
    children: []
};`
`var s = traverse(originalJson, destJson);`

Comment: are you sure, that `executors_num": "2"` and `"freq_in_mins": "180"` are not splitted in own objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz No. Only the JSON objects get splitted..

Comment: JSON is a special string format, not an object. if it is parsed, the it's not anymore a "*JSON*", but an Javascript object. please see here: http://json.org/.

Answer (score 0):

the code below is a recursive function that check if the object key is an object and if so its call it self

```js
var data = {
  "status": "CREATED",
  "overrides": {
    "name": "test_override"
  },
  "package_name": "test",
  "name": "app1",
  "defaults": {
    "job": {
      "example": {
        "executors_num": "2",
        "freq_in_mins": "180",
        "executors_mem": "256M",
        "job_name": "batch_example"
      }
    }
  }
}

function toArray(obj){
  var res = {children:[]}
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
     var childObj = {};
     
      if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
        childObj[key] = toArray(obj[key])
      }
      else{
        childObj[key] = obj[key]  
      }
     res.children.push(childObj)
   })
   return res;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(toArray(data)))
```

Comment: not exactly the answer I was looking for.. It adds an individual element as JSON object.. Instead, it should become a child of the parent array.

Answer (score 0):

Another proposal which adds for every property an own object in the children array.

```js
function organize(object, result, key) {
    if (typeof object === 'object') {
        result.obj = key;
        result.children = [];
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
            var o = {};
            result.children.push(o);
            organize(object[k], o, k);
        });
    } else {
        result[key] = object;
    }
}

var object = { "status": "CREATED", "overrides": { "name": "test_override" }, "package_name": "test", "name": "app1", "defaults": { "job": { "example": { "executors_num": "2", "freq_in_mins": "180", "executors_mem": "256M", "job_name": "batch_example" } } } },
    newObject = {};

organize(object, newObject)
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```